# Java: Regex removing any non decimal or '/' values

Tags: java, regex

I am trying to remove everything from a string except the decimal and the division sign '/'. 
So for example if the string is: "1.2/3x^7/1.1" 
it should return "1.2/3 7/1.1".

I have tried this: `s.replaceAll("^-?\\d*\\.?\\d?=^/", " ")` but it does nothing.

Comment: Strings are immutable. Did you assign the result of your `replaceAll` to a new String? `s = s.replaceAll("^-?\\d*\\.?\\d?=^/", " ")`.

Comment: What do you think `^` represents in your regex (you have two of them).

Comment: @Kon I just tried that and still no luck

Comment: Try `System.out.println("1.2/3x^7/1.1".replaceAll("(\\d+(?:[.]\\d+)?|/)|.", "$1"));` (the replacement can be `"$1 "` perhaps)

Comment: @pshemo Ahhh it cancels each other out...but if I just leave the first one in, I still get the same result...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This works

```
public static String decimalsAndDivision(String a) {
    return a.replaceAll("[^0-9./]", " ");
}
```

Use it like this:

```
System.out.println(decimalsAndDivision("1.2/3x^7/1.1"));
```

Comment: In fact, OP is looking for `a.replaceAll("[^0-9./]+", " ");`. Or even `.replaceAll("[^0-9./]+", " ").trim()`.